# getting text from spans using map and then assign them different text after check condition

Tags: jquery

hello i wanted to get text from different spans and then combine them using comma . i used `jquery map` for this and it worked fine . but i wanted to assign different values to them before they are joined by comma by specifying condition such as . if the value is `veg` then the new text will be `V` . my function is

```
var p_diet = $('.mipdiet ul li').find('span:first')
                                .map(function(){return $(this).text();})
                                .get()
                                .join(',');
```

from this i get the values i selected which is stored in different spans like `veg,non-veg`

i want to compare them before they are joined such that the output is `V,NV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to fully understand the question but I think this is what you want?

```
var arrValues = {
                'veg' : 'V',
                'non-veg' : 'NV',
                'meat' : 'M',
                'non-meat' : 'NM'
                }

var p_diet = $('.mipdiet ul li').find('span:first')
                                .map(function(){
                                    var text = $(this).text();
                                    return arrValues[text];
                                })
                                .get()
                                .join(',');
```

Tell me if that's what you want.

Comment: well i have four different values what would i have to change to get that work?

Comment: Boi you saved me from a code rewrite man . Thanks . This is something new i have experienced in jquery . Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, should work.

```
var ar= $('.mipdiet ul li').find('span:first')
                .map(function(){return $(this).text();})
                .map(function(){return this=='veg'?'V':this})
            .get().join();
```

Comment: this works for sure but how to do that for four different comparisions ?

Comment: Use switch inside the function. That would work, its just a function like all the rest. But the above will work as well.